# jquery kinetic enable standard vertical touch swipe

Tags: jquery, scroll, kineticjs

I use jquery kinetic to have a smooth horizontal div scroll (https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic).

It works great. However, on a touch device, jquery kinetic disable the normal vertical swipe/scroll gestures.
In my opinion, without a vertical scroll, you can do nothing on a touch device...if you have a full width container that use kinetic, you can't see what there is under or above the container...

If kinetic is setted up to only horizontal scroll, the vertical scroll is still disable.

Is there a way to enable the normal vertical scroll while using horizontal scroll with kinetic?

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem but I didn't want to use plugins because too many plugins will cause a huge unnecessary overhead for a mobile device.

So I wrote the following code - please note I am using

- jQuery mobile
- jQuery

jQuery mobile can provide you with the following events

```
$("#slider").css("transform","translateX(0px)");
$(document).off("touchstart").on('touchstart',touchStartHandler);
$(document).off("touchmove").on('touchmove',touchMoveHandler);
$(document).off("touchend").on('touchend',touchEndHandler);
```

You will need some global variables and some initialization for the div that will be slided

```
function touchStartHandler(event){

    touchStart = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    prevTouch = touchStart ;
    matrix = transMatrixToArray($("#slider").css("transform"));
    initSliderLeft = parseInt(matrix[4] , 10) ; };

function touchMoveHandler(event){


      var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];

      disFromStart = touch.pageX - touchStart.pageX ;
      var dis = touch.pageX - prevTouch.pageX ;
      //detecting swipe horizontally , this section should be entered once per swipe
      if( ! isSwiping && Math.abs(disFromStart) > 30 &&(Math.abs(touch.pageY - touchStart.pageY)< 80)){
            isSwiping = true ;
            $("#slider").css("transition-duration", "0s");

      }

      matrix1 = transMatrixToArray($("#slider").css("transform"));
      curTrans = matrix1[4] ;


      if( isSwiping && Math.abs(dis) > 0){
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#slider").css("transform","translateX("+( initSliderLeft + disFromStart  )+"px)");

        prevTouch = touch ;
      } }

function touchEndHandler(event){

isSwiping = false ;
var screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth ;


if( Math.abs(disFromStart) > (screenWidth /3) && (Math.abs(prevTouch.pageY - touchStart.pageY)< Math.abs(disFromStart)*3) ){
    if(disFromStart > 0){
        currentSubPage++ ;

    }else{
        currentSubPage-- ;
    }

}

$("#slider").css("transition-duration", "0.5s");
$("#slider").css("transform","translateX("+(screenWidth * currentSubPage)+"px)"); }

function transMatrixToArray(matrix) {
return matrix.substr(7, matrix.length - 8).split(', ');}
```

In this code I used css3 transitions to swipe a container div called slider 
this container wraps 3 full-width subPages